# How to send and email to the receiver after sender (admin) submit the form to database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I'm stuck on how to uses PHPMailer. I create a simple PHP form to book a meeting room. Admin needs to log in the system and key in all details including requester email's, factory and room. After admin click 'submit', it will save to database under table 'booking'.

Now, What I want is when I clicked the submit button, It also sent an email to the user about the details that already booked.

Below is my current code:

home.php

```
    <?php
        require_once 'configPDO.php';
        session_start();

        if(!ISSET($_SESSION['login_user'])){
            header('location:index.php');
        }

        $Email = $_SESSION['login_user'];
                    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE Email='$Email'");
                    $sql->execute();
                    $fetch = $sql->fetch();

        if(ISSET($_POST['submit'])){
            if($_POST['Requested_by'] != "" || $_POST['Factory'] != "" || $_POST['Room'] != ""){
                try{
                    $Requested_by = $_POST['Requested_by'];
                    $Factory = $_POST['Factory'];
                    $Room = $_POST['Room'];
                    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `booking` VALUES ('', '$Requested_by', '$Factory', '$Room')";
                    $conn->exec($sql);
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }

                $conn = null;
                header('location:index.php');
            }else{
                echo "
                    <script>alert('Please fill up the required field!')</script>
                    <script>window.location = 'registration.php'</script>
                ";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

sendmail.php

```
    <?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'PHPMailer/Mailer/Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/Mailer/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/Mailer/SMTP.php';

    require_once 'configPDO.php';
    session_start();

    $sendermail = '';
    $sendername = '';
    $senderpassword = '';
    $receiveremail = '';
    $receivername = '';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';  //gmail SMTP server
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = $sendermail;   //username
        $mail->Password = $senderpassword;   //password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';
        $mail->Port = 587;                    //smtp port

        $mail->setFrom($sendermail, $sendername);
        $mail->addAddress($receiveremail, $receivername);


        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'E-booking';
        $mail->Body    = '<h3>Dear '.$receivername.',</h3>';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    ?>
```

Please help me. thanks

Comment: In what way does the code fail?  How are these two PHP files related?  How are they being invoked?

Comment: how to link between those two codes?

Comment: Well, you could wrap your mailer code in a function, include it on the other page, and call that function.

Comment: I'm too beginner on this. Can you write the sample codes?